# Подключаюсь к бд Оракл, пытаюсь выгрзуить данные, но вместо этого выгружается None по полю Gender

Tags: python, oracle

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('Inventory_DB/%tgbvfr4@rhel6.office.lamoda.ru/PROD')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("Select art.SKU, art.product_sku, art.TARGETGROUP, "
            "DECODE(art.GENDER_1S,'Мужской', 'Men','Унисекс','Unisex','Девочки','Kids','Женский', 'Women','Детский унисекс','Kids','Мальчики','Kids') "
            "from v_dim_article art where brand='Charuel' ")

file = open('C:/test/emp2.csv', 'w')

for row in cur:
    sec = ', '.join(map(str, row))
    file.write(sec)
```

тот же код работает нормально если обращаться напрямую в SQL Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В результате нет поля GENDER, есть функция DECODE в которой русские названия меняются на английские. Если в таблице не русские названия, то логично, что в результате NULL. Но такой запрос и в девелопере будет NULL возвращать.

**Обновление**

Если в Developer все ок, тогда остается способ получения данных и кодировка. Если остальные поля получаются нормально, то со способом получения все в порядке. Надо пробовать изменить кодировку, например, так:

```
import os 
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".AL32UTF8"
```

или как предложено в соседнем ответе - заменить кодировку самого запроса. У Вас вероятнее всего русский в запросе не совпадает с русским в таблице, клиент и БД настроены в разных кодировках.

Comment: но в developer все ок

Comment: А что за "поле gender"? Синоним результату decode не дан ведь. Как ваш python-код знает, что такое gender?

Comment: то что предложено в первом ответе не помогло( сейчас попробую этот вариант

Comment: все работает спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поменять кодировку запроса, или целиком программы.
Поставьте первой строчкой в программе кодировку. 
Или конвертируйте строку в нужную вам кодировку с помощью encode()
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
cur.execute("Select art.SKU, art.product_sku, art.TARGETGROUP, "
            "DECODE(art.GENDER_1S,'Мужской', 'Men','Унисекс','Unisex','Девочки','Kids','Женский', 'Women','Детский унисекс','Kids','Мальчики','Kids') "
            "from v_dim_article art where brand='Charuel' ".encode('cp1251'))
```